# New privilege div broken

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface

It seems like the New Privilege `<div>` in Profile Page is broken on both the Desktop and Mobile site:

---

> **Desktop View**

[image: Image 1]

> This is what it should look like *apart from the colour scheme*:

[image: Image 2]

Image Source: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253662#253662)

> **Mobile View**

[image: Image 3]

It doesn't look to fit the styling.

---

**Browser:** Safari Version 10.0 AND Safari iOS

**OS:** macOS Sierra 10.12 AND iOS 10

Comment: I don't see what's broken.

Comment: @AndrewL. The Desktop View has the "Approve tag wiki edits" text blended in with the background. And the old div doesn't look like this

Comment: I still don't really see a 'bug'. Mobile is supposed to look different from desktop.

Comment: @AndrewL. Updated post to make it clearer

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your first picture since the misplaced text was kind of hard to spot.

Comment: I pinged the design team. Someone will look into this shortly.

Comment: @AdamLear Noted, thanks! :) I thought it might be broken by JQuery, so I posted it under there too.